# message.guild.members.getMember not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a user info command and DiscordJS keeps saying 
`TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function`

The function I'm using is this
`let target = message.guild.members.getMember(toFind);`

Is there something I need to update with a newer version of DiscordJS? I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Thanks,
Jude Wilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of Discord.js is v12, there has been many breaking changes

The function you are probably looking for is:

```
message.guild.members.fetch(id)
```

You will probably come across other issues, so check out this guide for moving from v11 to v12: 
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html

Comment: Whenever I try to use this I get the error: `reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` 

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Discord has a new update where you have to use .cache to access discord objects
for example: message.guild.members.cache

to get a user:

```js
let user = message.guild.members.cache.fetch("user id");
console.log(user.tag)

// if that doesn't work, use the same code but remove .cache
```