# discord js message.guild is always null message.member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i'm new with discord.js and i'm having a problem, i want to move to another voice channel the user that message my bot. I tryed many thing already, and every time when i want to get the member from msg it's null, msg.guild is also null and in don't get why

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    var params = msg.content.split(" ");
    if (params[0] === "!join" && params[1] != null) {
      channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == params[1] && c.type == "voice");
      member = msg.guild.members.get(msg.authorID);  
      member.voice.setChannel(channel)
    }
});
```

i tried this also and still : TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  var params = message.content.split(" ");
  if (params[0] === "!join" && params[1] != null) {
    channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == params[1] && c.type == "voice");
    message.guild.members.fetch(message.authorID)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version (v12) you should be doing

`message.guild.members.fetch(id)`

Refer to [this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) guide and a similar [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782924/message-guild-members-getmember-not-working) post

Also, make the message event asynchronous and use "message" as the parameter

`client.on("message", async message => {}`

Refer to docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message)

Comment: thx !  but i still got a  "Cannot read property 'members' of nul"

Comment: Did you change msg to message in the event arguments?

Comment: yes i did, and message.guild is  the problem, he is always null, so members is always undefined or null

Answer (score 0):

A message sent in private message to the both will not have a guild property, there is also the possibility of [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html)   but it is only on opt-in.

Comment: So i can't send a private message to the bot and then make him move me ?

Comment: Discord doesn't know which guild a private message should be associated to, so it sends nothing. You'd have to include additional logic for your bot to infer or store the guild for which commands in private message should apply.

Comment: you can try message.channel.members.fetch since the dmChannel is a channel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, maybe try `msg.guild.channels.cache.find` instead of client, since you're searching for a channel in a guild, not the client.
Second of all, try this for member `let member = msg.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === msg.author.id)`.
Each message has a author object that has an ID field, the message doesn't have an authorID, it has author.id

Answer (score 0):

i'm posting this because i found a quick solution (maybe not the best)
but if it can help someone

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  var params = message.content.split(" ");
  if (params[0] === "!join" && params[1] != null) {
    channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == params[1] && c.type == "voice"); // get the channel to join 
    member = server.members.cache.find(c => c.id === message.author.id)  // get the member
    member.voice.setChannel(channel);          //set the voice channel for the user  
  }
})
```

And the "server" var come from a global variable that i have,

```
server = client.guilds.cache.get('XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```